# How to check if a value is not equal to another value in the array using javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a user object as below and an array of location ids. I don't want the user.location_id to be equal to any value in the location_ids array stated as below using Javascript. Please help me achieve it.

```
user: {
  first_name: 'James',
  last_name: 'Smith',
  location_id: 21
},

location_ids:[23, 31, 16, 11]
```

So I want to

```
if (user.location_id != any value in the locations_ids array) {
 console.log("Select User")
}
```

Help me achieve this using javascript

Comment: `if (!location_ids.includes(user.location_id)) {
  console.log("Select user");
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to find if the element is present in the array or not.

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain
> value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate. - MDN

```
if(!location_ids.includes(user.location_id)){}
```

```js
const user = {
  first_name: "James",
  last_name: "Smith",
  location_id: 21,
};
const location_ids = [23, 31, 16, 11];

if (!location_ids.includes(user.location_id)) {
  console.log("Select user");
}

// Change location ID
user.location_id = 11;

if (!location_ids.includes(user.location_id)) {
  console.log("Select user");
} else {
  console.log("Don't select user");
}
```

Comment: OP does not want the `user.location_id` in the array so you should negate the `includes` result.

Comment: Thank you @decpk, great finding mate.

Comment: It is better to explain how your answer solved OP's problem....

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link] (https://techfunda.com/howto/729/not-equal-operator)

Here's [a link] (https://techfunda.com/howto/929/array-indexof-search)

```js
 
    function myFunction() {
        var a = ["France", "Nritian", "Israel", "Bhutan", "US", "UK"];
        var b = a.indexOf("Africa");
        document.getElementById("myId").innerHTML = b;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>Click the below button to know the output for an search which is not presented in an array.</p>
<input type="button", onclick="myFunction()" value="Find"/>
<p id="myId"></p>


</body>
</html>
```